# How do I combine Dependency Injection with Configuration Binding in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I haven't really used dependency injection much before, but it seems like a good fit for the .Net Core project I'm building now. It's a containerized non-ASP service (so essentially a console app), whose configuration is driven by a JSON file that looks like this:

```json
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "Name": "What's in a name?",
      "Description": "This is a description",

      "Source": {
        "Path": "SomePath/Read"
      },

      "Destination": {
        "Path": "SomePath/Write"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`Routes` can have `n` number of routes specified. Each one should resolve to a `Route` strongly-typed object and the Source and Destination sections should each resolve to a strongly-typed `FileLocation` object, with no manual mapping to JSON field names. The code below achieves this (with a top-level `Routes` class to contain the list):

```
new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(FileRoutesConfigFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build()
    .Get<Routes>()
```

However, I'd like for the configuration classes to benefit from the Microsoft DependencyInjection framework to get application services (e.g. something like this for `FileLocation`):

```cs
public class FileLocation {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    private IAppConfiguration AppConfiguration { get; }

    public FileLocation(IAppConfiguration appConfiguration) {
        AppConfiguration = appConfiguration;
    }
}
```

I can't see a way to do that (when there isn't a parameterless constructor it fails altogether). Do I need to use a different DI framework, or is there a way to accomplish this with the available first-party ones?

Comment: Configuration classes are models, don't put DI on them. Inject them into services and put whatever dependency you need there. To answer the actual question: I don't think you can do that with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Have a look at [Using HostBuilder and the Generic Host in .NET Core Microservices](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-generic-host-in-dotnet-core-console-based-microservices) and a closer look on [IOptions<TOptions>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking was to separate the options into their own strictly POCO classes, and then create factories to produce the more complex business classes with those as inputs. The factories can be constructed by the service provider, and injected into the classes that need to produce the JSON-configured classes. One of my factories, for an example, looks like this:

```cs
public interface IBusinessClassFactory
{
    IBusinessClass GetBusinessClass(BusinessClassConfig config);
}

public class BusinessClassFactory : IBusinessClassFactory
{
    public BusinessClassFactory(AppConfig appConfig, ISubclassFactory subclassFactory,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        AppConfig = appConfig;
        SubclassFactory = subclassFactory;
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public AppConfig AppConfig { get; }
    public ISubclassFactory SubclassFactory { get; }
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

    public IBusinessClass GetBusinessClass(BusinessClassConfig config)
    {
        var logger = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<FileLocation>>();
        return new BusinessClass(logger, AppConfig, SubclassFactory, config);
    }
}
```

This way, I can still isolate the classes from each other for unit testing, and retain most of the dependency map at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

i think Autofac or Scrutor might be helpful. IServiceCollection might not have it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using the HostBuilder class. [Here](https://thecodebuzz.com/dependency-injection-console-app-using-generic-hostbuilder/) you can find an example.

Comment: I followed the link you gave, and HostBuilder looks interesting, but I don't see how it works any differently for the case I'm asking about than implementing `ConfigureServices()` in my Program.cs

Comment: If [this](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/october/strongly-typed-configuration-sections-with-options-pattern-in-aspnet-core/) is not what you mean, then it probably doesn't support it out of the box.